# How to fix page view controller?

Tags: ios, uipagecontrol

Ive set up a page view controller, But now I need it to work with 2 view controllers?

Would anyone know how I can connect the Page View Controller with the 2 other view controllers???

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers direction:
```

This is the method that adds your view controllers to your PageViewController.

Comment: Great - I'll play with that for a while, please comment here so I can update you if I run into trouble!